# Nuxt subdomain only works with localhost

Tags: dns, localhost, nuxt.js, subdomain

I need to get subdomain on Nuxt. So I use       `const domain = window.location.hostname` and it works perfectly fine when for exemple I try `exemple.localhost:3000`
But when I try to change the hosts and try to do `exemple.mydomain:3000` my browser can't find it while `mydomain:3000` works

`nuxt` launch script as `dev`:

```
nuxt --hostname 'mydomain' --port 3000
```

and etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       mydomain      mydomain.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`nuxt.config.js` :

```
server: {
    host: 'mydomain'
    port: 3000
}
```